# reading and modying the value of the .properties file by shell script in unix

Tags: unix, scripting, properties-file

hi i am updating the value until the key is simple...
but the problems come when i encountered the key like user.name

following is the properties file:-

```
user.name=sandeep
class=a1
```

following is the script:-

```
. /pro.properties


b=$(echo $user.name)

sed -i "s|$b|rohit|g" ./pro.properties

cat pro.properties
```

i want to only change the value of it from sandeep to rohit

i have also tried it with the following:-

1. echo $user.name
2. echo ${user.name}
3. echo $(user.name)
4. echo $'user.name'
5. echo $`user.name`
6. echo $"user.name"
7. a='user.name'
   b=$(echo $a)

but it is not getting the value of that key

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't allow variables with a "." in the middle of the name.

bash-3.2$ user.name=sandeep
bash: user.name=sandeep: command not found

You could use the following command to change the line.

sed  "s|user.name=sandeep|user.name=rohit|g" <./pro.properties >./pro.new